# Get js console.log as python variable in QWebView pyqt

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt, plotly, qwebview

I'm trying to build an application that creates some `html + js` code with python and loads it into a QWebView.

The final `html + js` code is the following (raw code available [here](https://gist.github.com/ghtmtt/aa30a7d65fe380c85ba4680a4b98e427)):

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head><div id="myDiv" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" class="plotly-graph-div"></div><script type="text/javascript">window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};window.PLOTLYENV.BASE_URL="https://plot.ly";Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", [{"type": "scatter", "x": [6.81, 6.78, 6.49, 6.72, 6.88, 7.68, 7.69, 7.38, 6.76, 6.84, 6.91, 6.74, 6.77, 6.73, 6.68, 6.94, 6.72], "y": [1046.67, 1315.0, 1418.0, 997.33, 2972.3, 9700.0, 6726.0, 6002.5, 2096.0, 2470.0, 867.0, 2201.7, 1685.6, 2416.7, 1618.3, 2410.0, 2962.0], "mode": "markers", "ids": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]}], {"showlegend": true}, {"linkText": "Export to plot.ly", "showLink": false})</script>
<script>    
    var plotly_div = document.getElementById('myDiv')
    var plotly_data = plotly_div.data
    plotly_div.on('plotly_selected', function(data){
    featureId = plotly_data[0].ids[data.points[0].pointNumber]
    featureIds = []
    data.points.forEach(function(pt) {
    featureIds.push(parseInt(pt.id))
        })
    console.log(featureIds)
    })
</script>
```

This code creates a plot thanks to `plotly` python API. By saving the plot in a local file (e.g. `/home/matteo/plot.html`) I'm able to load it in the QWebView with the following piece of code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import json

plot_view = QWebView()
plot_view.page().setNetworkAccessManager(QgsNetworkAccessManager.instance())
plot_view_settings = plot_view.settings()
plot_view_settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.WebGLEnabled, True)
plot_view_settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
plot_view_settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.Accelerated2dCanvasEnabled, True)

plot_path = '/home/matteo/plot.html'
plot_url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(plot_path)
plot_view.load(plot_url)
plot_view.show()
```

The javascript function of above simply return the ids of the selected points of the plot in the javascript console when using the `lasso selection` tool of the plot.

Checking with the `inspect` tool, it works fine also in the QWebView: each time an element is within the selection, in the console.log I can see the corresponding id of the point.

This is a static image taken from jsfiddle (lasso selection, point selected and console.log output):

[image]

the running code is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4qacpr36/), just enable the debugging console and select some point with the lasso selection tool.

What I'd really like to achieve is to take the output of the console (so the ids of the selected points), and re-inject them into the application in order to have an usable python object (list, dictionary, whatever) every time I make a selection.

Is there a way to link the javascript console of the QWebPage in order to obtain python objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `console.log()` output, it is only necessary to overwrite the method [javaScriptConsoleMessage()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebpage.html#javaScriptConsoleMessage).

*Plus:* I have added 2 ways to access the list of points, the first is through the attribute obj, and the second through a signal.

```
class _LoggedPage(QWebPage):
    obj = [] # synchronous
    newData = pyqtSignal(list) #asynchronous
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, msg, line, source):
        l = msg.split(",")
        self.obj = l
        self.newData.emit(l)
        print ('JS: %s line %d: %s' % (source, line, msg))
```

**complete example:**

```
class _LoggedPage(QWebPage):
    obj = [] # synchronous
    newData = pyqtSignal(list) #asynchronous
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, msg, line, source):
        l = msg.split(",")
        self.obj = l
        self.newData.emit(l)
        print ('JS: %s line %d: %s' % (source, line, msg))

def onNewData(data):
    print("asynchronous", data)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
plot_view = QWebView()
page = _LoggedPage()
page.newData.connect(onNewData)

plot_view.setPage(page)
plot_path = '/home/qhipa/plot.html'
plot_url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(plot_path)
plot_view.load(plot_url)
plot_view_settings = plot_view.settings()
plot_view_settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.WebGLEnabled, True)
plot_view_settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
plot_view_settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.Accelerated2dCanvasEnabled, True)

# synchronous request simulation
timer = QTimer(plot_view)
timer.timeout.connect(lambda: print("synchronous", page.obj))
timer.start(1000)

plot_view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I used you code and it works. However, I'm not able to *store* the output in a variable that I can use in a second moment. Editing your code by adding ``obj = []`` right before the ``javaScriptConsoleMessage`` and then trying to returning the object ``retunr self.obj`` I get always the same error: `TypeError: invalid result from _LoggedPage.javaScriptConsoleMessage()`. Am I missing something? Thanks again!

Comment: perfect! Thanks!